# WPF: ItemsControl and DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext, itemscontrol

I have a main window with a single user control in it, called `SuperMode`. `SuperMode` consists of a collection of people and each person in this collection has their own collection of tasks. Sounds simple, right?

From file `SuperMode.xaml`:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Prototype.SuperMode"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prototype"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> <!-- NOTE! -->
    <!-- Look at how I'm setting the DataContext, as I think it's
         important to solve the problem! -->

    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

This works fine and I can see *four* people as I expect! Now all I have to do is get the XAML right for the `Person` user control so that all of their tasks are displayed as well.

As you can see, I'm using the `People` property to populate the control with items. The `People` property has type `ObservableCollection<Person>`, where `Person` is another user control as such...

From `Person.xaml`:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Prototype.Person"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prototype">

    <Border Background="Black" CornerRadius="4" Margin="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

`Tasks` here is a property of `Person` with type `ObservableCollection<Task>`. This is where it gets stuck! Apparently WPF cannot find any `Tasks` property and looking at the output window from VS2008, I find the following:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'Tasks' property not found on 'object' ''SuperMode' (Name='SuperMode')'. BindingExpression:Path=Tasks; DataItem='SuperMode' (Name='SuperMode'); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Now I'm lost. It seems that I have to set the `DataContext` attribute on each `Person`, otherwise it will still think that the data context is `SuperMode`, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the rather unpleasant design you have (you should look into MVVM), you should be able to set the `DataContext` for the child `UserControl`s as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.DataContext" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and get back to you. Do you happen to have a link to a good place where I can see a real-world example of MVVM in action complete with source code and explanation?